# Scoping in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I noticed in most of the scoping you mostly pass a where clause or a lambda.  But I'm trying to do something like this and it won't work

```
class LesleyGrade < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :my_scope, select('STC_TERM_GPA, max(TERM), max(last), max(first)').group('STC_TERM_GPA').order('max(first), max(term) ASC')

end
```

Just for reference here's my table:

```
Lesley Grade
------------
id
first
last
stc_term_gpa
term
```

When I called `LesleyGrade.term_gpa` this is what I get:

```
  LesleyGrade Load (27.9ms)  SELECT STC_TERM_GPA, max(TERM), max(last), max(first) FROM "lesley_grades"  GROUP BY STC_TERM_GPA  ORDER BY max(first), max(term) ASC
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for #<LesleyGrade::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdf9ab13d08>
from /Users/garytsai/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
```

Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope body must be wrapped in a proc or lambda, so just change it to:

```
scope :my_scope, -> { 
  select('STC_TERM_GPA, max(TERM), max(last), max(first)').group('STC_TERM_GPA').order('max(first), max(term) ASC')
}
```